# How do i create an Anonymous method that returns void?

Tags: c#

the `Func` generic fucntion does not take `void` as an argument therefore i cannot create an anonymous method that returns `void`, but is there a way to create a anonymous method that returns `void`?

Comment: `Action` might be your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Action<T,...>` instead of `Func<T,...>`. It doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 5):

`Func<>` doesn't work without return value - you have to use `Action<>` instead

example:

```
Action<string> act = x => Console.WriteLine(x); 
act("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Action` for this purpose:

```
public void Method()
{

}
```

`new Action(Method)` returns a valid delegate